# How to pass literal JavaScript code to Yii framework methods?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am generating a checkbox using the corresponding method of `CHtml`, and I want to run some JavaScript code before and after the AJAX request. Here is the code:

```
echo CHtml::checkBox('markComplete', FALSE, 
    array(
        'class' => 'markComplete',
        'ajax'  => array(
            'type'       => 'POST',
            'url'        => $this->createUrl('/events/events/MarkComplete'),
            'data'       => 'event_status='.$events['id'],
            'beforeSend' => 'function(){ $(this).parent("TR").hide(); }',
            'success'    => 'function(resp) { $("#right").append(resp); }'
        ),
    )
);
```

How can I tell Yii that `beforeSend` and `success` are JavaScript code and not plain strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Better option available starting from Yii 1.1.11

All framework classes now support custom JavaScript snippets through [`CJavaScriptExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJavaScriptExpression). Use it like this:

```
'ajax' => array(
    'beforeSend' => new CJavaScriptExpression(
        'function(){ $(this).parent("TR").hide(); }'
    ),
    // ...
)
```

The option of prefixing strings with `js:` is still available by default, but it can now be disabled as required using an optional parameter on [`CJavaScript::encode`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJavaScript#encode-detail).

### Original answer

If you want to include literal JavaScript code as part of options, the convention in Yii is to prefix the code with `js:`. So you would write it like this:

```
'ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'url'=>$this->createUrl('/events/events/MarkComplete'),
    'data'=>'event_status='.$events['id'],
    'beforeSend' => 'js:function(){            
        $(this).parent("TR").hide();

    }',
    'success'=>'js:function(resp) {
        $("#right").append(resp);

    }'
    ),
)
```

Unfortunately this is not well documented, which is why people run into [exactly this problem](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=2067) every now and then.

Comment: if console.log it... it show error on firebug console.

**
elem.nodeName is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

...ks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.typ...

jquery.js (line 2317)**

Comment: when i print $(this) in console it returns me ajax object

Comment: @AlizainPrasla: That means that your code needs debugging, not that putting `js:` in front isn't what you should do. So go ahead and debug it; unfortunately I can't help with that.